# haystack can't parse a query

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I am working on a Django application and want to perform some queries. I use haystack with solr. I have a model `B` that has a `foreign_key` to model `A`. I need to get object of `A` that has certain id. Then I need to get all objects of `B` that point to it.

I tried:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=something).models(A).filter(id__in=[id_of_A_object_i_need]).models(B)
```

And I got an error:

> SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 400): [Reason: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse '( AND id:("18"))': Encountered " AND "AND "" at line 1, column 2.
>   Was expecting one of:
>       NOT ...
>       "+" ...
>       "-" ...
>       BAREOPER ...
>       "(" ...
>       "*" ...
>       QUOTED ...
>       TERM ...
>       PREFIXTERM ...
>       WILDTERM ...
>       REGEXPTERM ...
>       "[" ...
>       "{" ...
>       LPARAMS ...
>       "filter(" ...
>       NUMBER ...
>       TERM ...
>       ]

Can you help me?

Comment: Why are you using Haystack for this? These kinds of queries should be done directly in the database. Haystack with Solr is good for keyword or full-text searches.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the type of searches I need to do.